# How do I keep others from pairing their compatible device with my Android phone via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I'm going to use the mysterious Bluetooth feature on my Samsung J7 to play music from my phone while I listen with wireless headphones paired to my device. Apparently, all anyone has to do is turn on Bluetooth and it will show a list of all the nearby devices you can connect to. How do I keep neighbors etc. from pairing with my phone while I'm listening to music via Bluetooth?

Comment: Pairing doesn't happen automatically or by default. You get an indication on your phone intimation you that a device is seeking permission to pair. Simply refuse

Comment: See this for images of pairing requests https://www.google.co.in/search?q=bluetooth+pairing+request&client=ms-android-motorola&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHjcqPy63UAhVJKo8KHbKADB8Q_AUICSgB&biw=360&bih=512&dpr=3

Answer (score 2):

turn off your bluetooth visibility, by this way the media center will not be able to detect your bluetooth, but you will still be able to connect to other devices. For suppose if still showing pairing request means try using some friends phone and connect to mediacenter, so when the other phone is gone from your home, mediacenter might remember that phone and stop sending you connection requests

Comment: try this method if it doesn't work means inform me! i will give you an another solution

Comment: is this helped or not ??